# Google analytics, users

Tags: javascript, php, google-analytics

I have had Google analytics on my webpage for about three years now.
My page is very specific, it's written in Swedish.
My potential users are about 1000 persons, 1500 at most.

Previous years Google analytics have shown what I assume is correct data.
Looking at May previous year it shows 332 users.
May this year 12287 users.
And that is not in any way possible.

If I look at where my users are from it's 99.89 from Sweden meaning it's not Google analytics "spam".

I have have not changed anything in the code since 2016-ish.

Is there anything in the JavaScript code that needs to be changed to get correct results?

I have added some custom dimensions to the JavaScript.

UserId is a calculated number that originated from the users IP.
Maybe this is tin foil hat theory, but is this due to GDPR?
Or can something be changed to make it correct?

as php code

```
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
    $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
}elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
    $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
} else {
    $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}
$ip=str_replace(".","",$ip)*2;

if (isset($_COOKIE['Hoppvader'])){
    $Cookie = "Y";   
    $no = count(explode(",", $_COOKIE['Hoppvader']));
}else {
    $Cookie = "N";   
    $no = 0;
}

?>
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxxx',{ 'userId': '<?=$ip;?>' }, 'auto');

  ga('require', 'linkid', 'linkid.js');
  ga('require', 'displayfeatures');
  ga('send', 'pageview', {
      'dimension1':  '<?=$ip;?>',
      'dimension2':  '<?=$Cookie;?>',
      'dimension3':  '<?=$no;?>'
    });

</script>
```

In html:

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxx',{ 'userId': '1574427072' }, 'auto');

  ga('require', 'linkid', 'linkid.js');
  ga('require', 'displayfeatures');
  ga('send', 'pageview', {
      'dimension1':  '1574427072',
      'dimension2':  'Y',
      'dimension3':  '15'
    });

</script>
```

---

Bounty edit:

I have added a dashboard page for you to see my data.
http://www.hoppvader.nu/Stats.html
As you can see there is a massive spike in users over from one day to another.
If you want any other data please just ask and I will try to add it as soon as possible.

I also added php and javascript tags in case that is part of the problem.
Php for generating the javascript tag used to send the data to GA.

Comment: What are your server logs showing? How much of a difference is it compared to GA's numbers?

Comment: @vinoaj Hard to say. I don't know what my server is counting. It shows "visits", Don't know if that is pageviews or users. But looking at may 26, GA shows 597 users and 881 pageviews, the server shows 175 "visits".

Comment: What are your GA sessions for the same period? "Visits" usually equate to "Sessions" in GA.

Comment: May 26 had 631 sessions.

Comment: Can you provide the URL of your site? Using GA Debugger (Chrome Extention) its really easy to detect this kind of problem.On the other hand, have you checked if the spikes affect all sources of traffic and all pages "equally"? If this is the case then the problem is on site most probably.

Comment: @Marco  Not sure how to check if it's equally. I have a look at the data and see if I can see something. Webpage is http://www.hoppvader.nu

Comment: @Marco I think I found a way to answer your question. I created a custom report in GA where i list pages and count of IP. IP is what should be the userID. Looking at the spreadsheet http://hoppvader.nu/Analytics%20All%20Web%20Site%20Data%20users%20per%20page%2020180501-20180623.xlsx the number of IPs seems correct. 320 on the main landingpage seems correct. Settings and cookie pages are also universal pages thus a higher count. So it seems my code does not work. The userID I write in code is not honored by GA in the data.

Comment: If you look at the "dataset" sheet there is a list of all the "IPs", if I remove all the duplicates I get the 565 unique IPs. Which again seems fine.

Answer (score 0):

One of three possibilities seem logical here.

One is that your user ID is changing across the session, meaning that from pageview to pageview it's changing.

Two is that your user ID is coming in as a default value and being counted multiple times.

Three is your tag is firing more than once on your site or specific pages.

I suggest using the Chrome Extension from Google called Tag Assistant and viewing your key pages, looking at how many pageviews and what data is being sent to GA

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tag-assistant-by-google/kejbdjndbnbjgmefkgdddjlbokphdefk?hl=en

Comment: As I wrote the ID is the IP, but since google don't allow you to store IP's I removed the dots and multiply with 2. That way I or anyone else can't reverse the number to an IP. I tried using the google tag assistant but I could not see anything that looked odd. It reported in green or blue and as far as I can see no errors. All pages run the same php code that includes the same google analyics script. The code can't be different on any of the pages.

Answer (score 0):

check your http/https/www versions, also check in older google analytics version last year I got same glitch my older data wasn't reflecting newer version.